# Error, word is not displaying one letter at a time

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make sure that when a word is shown, it will be shown letter for letter. However, this is not working. And I am keep getting an error.

I have already looked on StackOverflow to see if there are other people that have the same problem as I do. There are people with the same goal, yet, I cannot find anyone with the same problem. The programming language that I am using to reach this goal is JavaScript.

The code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
  document.documentElement.addEventListener('load',function(evt){
  alert('OK');
  },false);

  var text = 'dog';
  var curr = "";
  var Write = function write(){
    var elem = document.getElementById('cls-3');
    elem.textContent += text.charAt(curr);
    curr++;
    if (curr < text.length)
      window.setTimeout(write, 20);
};

 Write();
    ]]></script>
```

The error:

> Logo_infomaatje.svg?version=3613:51  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'textContent' of null
>       at write (Logo_infomaatje.svg?version=3613:51)
>       at Logo_infomaatje.svg?version=3613:56

With this code, I am expecting that the word "dog" will be spelled out a letter for letter. This is unfortunately not happening. I hope that I have provided enough information.

Greetings,

Parsa237

Comment: Does your HTML code have an element with `id="cls-3"` ?

Comment: Hey... I mean JavaScript lets you do that but why are you initializing `curr` as string and then increase it by 1? If you want to program in other languages this will definitely cause you problems. (BTW: not complaining just trying to help ^^ :) ) For example if you try to do: `curr += 1` it will result in `curr` beeing `"1"` and not `1``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stefan said in the comment, i think that when the line `var elem = document.getElementById('cls-3');` is executed, there's no `cls-3` element in your html.

Maybe this element is never created, or maybe your javascript code is executed before this element creation.

According to your code, `Write()` is called immediately instead of waiting for the DOM loaded event. You should try this:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('load',function(evt){
    alert('OK');
    Write();
},false);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I now realize that I have accidentally included a class and not an id. So I will change that. I will also try the code you have given me above.